# [AWS][Api Gateway] Can HTTP Apis make asynchronous invocation to Lamda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm starting to build some service with Aws. I have built Rest Apis make Asynchronous request to Lambda function via add header X-Amz-Invocation-Type: 'Event' at Integration request. Yeah, that worked.
But I'm trying to build like that but with Http Apis. I added that header: X-Amz-Invocation-Type to request from Postman but this request is not Asynchronous.
Can someone help me, please?

Comment: I don't think its possible to do this directly. But indirectly you could proxy your call through async lambda which would call http endpoint.

Comment: thank @SurajBhatia, maybe I will switch to another APIs :))